# How to change Logger Configuration at Runtime using MvvmCross and Serilog on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, serilog

I configured ILogger using Xamarin.Forms with [MvvmCross](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/logging-new) like so:

```
public class Setup : MvxFormsAndroidSetup<App, UI.App>
{
    ...

    protected override ILoggerProvider CreateLogProvider()
    {
        return new SerilogLoggerProvider();
    }

    protected override ILoggerFactory CreateLogFactory()
    {
        Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Is(_logEventLevel)
            .CreateLogger();

        return new SerilogLoggerFactory();
    }
    ...
```

Where *_logEventLevel* has a default value and everything logs as expected. At runtime I'm changing this value and want to register a new Logger. How do i register a new *LoggerConfiguration* with my updated *_logEventLevel*?

I tried calling *MvxSetup.InitializeLoggingServices()* but it still won't log the updated MinimumLevel.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need a new logger configuration? Is it to set a new minimum level?

Comment: Yes, it is. My workaround was to handle minimum level in my custom LogEventSink, but it would be nicer to not log unneeded levels at all.

Comment: You are looking for LoggingLevelSwitch to be able to switch it, then you don't need to instantiate a new configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the comments you say you want to change the configuration because you want to be able to change the log level during runtime. For that you don't need to instantiate a new configuration, you can use LogginLevelSwitch instead.

So this would look something like:

```
SeriLogLevelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(SeriLogLevelSwitch)
```

Then later you can just change `SeriLogLevelSwitch.MinimumLevel` to something else:

```
SeriLogLevelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
```

Comment: Cool, works perfectly! Thanks. Classic case of looking for a wrong solution to a problem:)